# How do you add pop-up help after an html text field with a question mark graphic?

Tags: javascript, html, button

Here is what I have now:

```
<button type="button" name="moreinfo" id="moreinfo"  onClick=" var a = findPos(this); RevLevel(a[0], a[1]); "> <img src="images/question.png" height="16" width="17" alt="more info" border="0" /> </button>`
```

I'm using Firefox 15.0.1 and I'm getting a button around my question mark graphic.  I just want the question mark graphic without a button shape around it.

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Code please, try making a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just attach the tool-tip and the click event to the image itself?

```
<img name='moreinfo' id='moreinfo' onclick=" var a = findPos(this); RevLevel(a[0], a[1]); " src="images/question.png" height="16" width="17" alt="more info" border="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#moreinfo{
border-width:0;
background-color:transparent;  
}
```

**Tip 1:**
You could bind your event directly to the img, since you don't need the appearance of a button. Then, you don't need a button.

**Tip 2:** 
Separate your JS logic from your HTML code. Bind your listeners in a script block or a separated JS file.

**Tip 3:**
The button tag doesn't need a type attribute, this is needed for input elements, not for a button.

**Tip 4:**
As I mentioned above about JS, separate your CSS from your HTML as well. Do it in a style tag or a separated stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Like *Mr. Alien* said, you can do it with CSS. Another approach is to surround the `<img>` tag with an `<a>` tag instead of a `<button>` tag:

```
 <p>Some Text 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('Some information...');">
       <img src="images/question.png"/>
     </a>
 </p>
```